# Corda - SignTransactionFlow and sendAndReceive

Tags: blockchain, corda

I have two parties (A and B).
A sends to B a Corda State using **SignTransactionFlow**, so also obtains the counterparty signature for that transaction.

Is it possibile to share a Corda State without using a SignTransactionFlow but using a **sendAndReceive** calls?
If so, will the counterparty receiving a Corda State through sendAndReceive be able to consume that state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to send states using `send()` and `receive()`. Here is a code sample that I tested to see if it works:

```
class TestContract : Contract{
    companion object{
        @JvmStatic
        val ID = "package net.corda.sample.TestContract"
    }
    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {

    }
}
@BelongsToContract(TestContract::class)
class TestState(val owner : Party, val value : String) : ContractState {
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty>
        get() = listOf(owner)
}


@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class receiveStateFlow(private val counterparty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()
    val log = loggerFor<receiveStateFlow>()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val counterpartySession = initiateFlow(counterparty)
        val counterpartyData = counterpartySession.sendAndReceive<TestState>("hello")
        counterpartyData.unwrap { msg ->
            log.warn(msg.value)
            assert((msg.participants.first()) == counterparty)
        }
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(receiveStateFlow::class)
class sendStateFlow(private val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val counterpartyData = counterpartySession.receive<String>()
        counterpartyData.unwrap { msg ->
            assert(msg == "hello")
        }
        val newState = TestState(serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first(), "someValue")
        counterpartySession.send(newState)
    }
}
```

However, this method will not consume any states. This can only happen if you use those states as the output of a `Transaction`. Hence, the Party that receives the states should use those exact states as a output in a `TransactionBuilder` in the same Flow and go on with signing and finalising the transaction.